# Can't find a place to bind paredit's convolute-sexp

Tags: emacs, clojure, paredit

Strangely, while the various paredit cheatsheets show <kbd>M-?</kbd> bound to `paredit-convolute-sexp`, the `paredit.el` file doesn't have any binding for that function, though it does define the function. I edited `paredit.el` to add it here:

```el
 ....
("M-q"  paredit-reindent-defun)
("M-\?" paredit-convolute-sexp)
```

But after restarting emacs, it is still not bound to <kbd>M-?</kbd>. I tried using just `"M-?"` in the binding with no backslash, but made no difference.

I also tried to do this:

```el
(defun my-clojure-hook ()
  (auto-complete-mode 1)
  (define-key clojure-mode-map
    (kbd "M-\?" 'paredit-convolute-sexp)))

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'my-clojure-hook)
```

Also tried with and without the backslash.

That also made no difference, even though it does turn on auto complete mode fine.

Can anyone advise where I should put this binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a close parenthesis on your call to `kbd`.  Your hook should read as follows (incidentally, I don't think you need to escape the question mark):

```el
(defun my-clojure-hook ()
  (auto-complete-mode 1)
  (define-key clojure-mode-map
    (kbd "M-?") 'paredit-convolute-sexp))
```

And actually, the call to `define-key` only needs to be made once (say, in your .emacs file) rather than every time you open a new clojure buffer, so you don't need to put it in the hook per se.

Comment: Glad to help!  Enjoy.